# Dagger 2.11 injection not working for fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, dependency-injection, dagger-2

Hi i am trying to inject dependencies on my Android Fragment class the same way i do for my activity and it doesnt seem to inject the objects into my variables in the fragment.

Here is my binding module

```
@Module
abstract class HomeAndroidBinding{

    /**
     * Activity bindings here
     */
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [MyModule ::class])
    @MyScope
    abstract fun bindHomeActivity() : HomeActivity

    /**
     * Fragment Bindings here
     */
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [MyModule ::class])
    @MyScope
    abstract fun bindHomeFragment() : HomeFragment
}
```

Here is my Fragment class

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

   @Inject
    lateinit var productStorage: ProductStorageContract //error, not inialised

    ...

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        productStorage.getData()
    }
```

This is my ApplicationComponent that loads and binds everything

```
    @Singleton
@Component(modules = arrayOf(MyMainModule::class,
        AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class,
        HomeAndroidBinding::class,
        ))
interface ApplicationComponent : AndroidInjector<DaggerApplication> {
    fun inject(myApplication: MyApplication)
    override fun inject(instance: DaggerApplication)

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {
        @BindsInstance
        fun application(applicaton: MyApplication): Builder

        fun build(): ApplicationComponent
    }


}
```

The same var of productStorage works fine on the HomeActivity

Answer (score 3):

You also need to include following in your fragment:

```
override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
    AndroidSupportInjection.inject(this)
    super.onAttach(context)
}
```

Full example of this in: https://github.com/joreilly/galway-bus-android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/surrus/galwaybus/ui/RoutesFragment.kt

Comment: Umm , so not like activity where i dont need it?

Comment: I believe you need to also call `AndroidInjection.inject()` in your activity as well (or at least that's what I'm doing right now!)

Comment: No i dont on my activities

Comment: hmm, not sure tbh how that would work.....going from following for example https://medium.com/@iammert/new-android-injector-with-dagger-2-part-1-8baa60152abe

Comment: yes it worked but not ideal as you need to add that to each fragment = boiler plate code

Comment: @jonney Show us your Activity. You may be inheriting from DaggerActivity (which contains that code in a superclass), and if you are, then you can use DaggerFragment to remove similar "boilerplate".

Comment: if i have one page with 2 frags and another page with 3 frags. can i just implement HasSupportFragmentInjector in both the activity ?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Jeff Browman.

The issue was that my fragment was not using DaggerFragment super class